# Is my infinitesimal generator matrix correct?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, markov-chains, birth-death-process

Consider a telegraph system consisting of two independently operating wires, each capable of processing one message at a time. The time that each cable remains in operation until it breaks down is a random variable with exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$. The repair time of each cable has an exponential distribution with parameter $\mu$, however, for each $t \geq 0$, we denote by $X(t)$ the number of cables operating at the same time. Define the stochastic process we are considering and its states, later:
a) Determine the infinitesimal generator of the chain

I've tried this:

The infinitesimal generator of the chain is:
$$ 
Q=
\begin{bmatrix}
-\mu & \mu & 0 \\
\lambda & -(\lambda+\mu) & \mu \\
0 & \lambda & -\lambda \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that each wire is repaired independently, the matrix should be as follows:

$$ 
Q=
\begin{bmatrix}
-2\mu & 2\mu & 0 \\
\lambda & -(\lambda+\mu) & \mu \\
0 & 2\lambda & -2\lambda \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Assuming that only one wire can be repaired at a time, then only the third row would differ. Otherwise you are correct.